# Null values in Django sub-model

Tags: django, django-models

Can someone explain this simple, yet deceiving, anomaly?

There are two models, where `B` is a sub-model of `A`:

```
# models.py
class A(models.Model):
    a = models.IntegerField(blank=True)

class B(A):
    b = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
```

Simple, right? Yet in runtime:

```
>>> A()
<A: A object>
>>> B()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "django/db/models/base.py", line 357, in __init__
    setattr(self, field.attname, val)
  File "django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 271, in __set__
    (instance._meta.object_name, self.related.get_accessor_name()))
ValueError: Cannot assign None: "B.b" does not allow null values.
```

What's happening here? Why is `A.a` acting fine while `B.b` is unhappy about itself being blank?

---

Edit: I did notice that setting `blank=True` makes no difference on said behavior, but that still doesn't explain this issue.

And now this: (?!?!?!)

```
>>> a = A(a=5)
>>> b = B(b=6)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "django/db/models/base.py", line 357, in __init__
    setattr(self, field.attname, val)
  File "django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 275, in __set__
    self.related.get_accessor_name(), self.related.opts.object_name))
ValueError: Cannot assign "6": "B.b" must be a "B" instance.
```

Comment: The more I think about this the more this seems like a bug. Follow https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18480 for developments

Comment: I'm inclined to agree. I just ran this same test and have the same error (django 1.2). Even setting A to be abstract does not sort this out. The validation shouldn't fail unless you're trying to save the instance - but it's the relation descriptor that's failing here..

Comment: Oh, and setting null=True will solve this particular error, but you should be able to construct objects without values, and save them at a later time.

Comment: What version of django are you using?

Comment: Ohhh! This isn't about the field at all.. this is all about conflicting field names!

Comment: Yep, I just figured that out. Thanks Josh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I managed to solve this mess.

The problem here is that the model and the field have the same name (case-agnostic). I had this both in my problematic model, as well as the examples here (`A.a` and `B.b`).

This is a Django problem in that the error is simply irrelevant to the real issue.

Bottom line - don't have any field the same name as the model name.

Comment: I'll stop writing my answer now :P

Comment: Just accept your own answer mate, but I'll provide more information in a comment.

Comment: To add further information though, to access `B` from `A`, `A` gets an attribute `b` that refers to the instance of `B` in the reverse relation. This 'shadows' the `b` attribute defined directly on `B` due to inheritance. Field shadowing is prohibited in the django inheritance model.. though I can't find the documentation mentioning that at this point.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#field-name-hiding-is-not-permitted